# How to style Asp.net GridView cells with colour based on cell value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `Gridview` , it have a column called `student_Class`. There are around of 80 Class on grid view. I have grouped this class using GroupBy query.

Now I want to Style this different class with different color. How is it possible?
It is not easy to write all classes on `RowDataBound` and giving color.

Is there any other way?

**Code:**

```
groups = (ArrayList)Session["selectedclass"];
SELECT id,name,student_Class FROM student where 
         student_Class='"+groups[0].ToString().Trim()+"'  
         group by  student_Class.
```

Gives Data as

```
 id   name   student_class
 1    aa      A
 2    bb      A
 3    cc      A
 4    dd      B
 5    ee      B
 6    as      B
 7    ss      B
 8    AZZ     D
```

The student class with value  `A` need same color(for cell) and `B` need other color., etc.

Comment: What is your criteria for giving different colour to a cell.??

Comment: student_class with same class have same color  @Ankur  Karl Anderson

Comment: For you have binded the grid with the values from the database, run a loop from 0 till grid row count and according to your requirment . Use below line to give color to the cell

grd_AssetDistri.Rows[0].Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.YOURCOLOR;

Comment: Ankur, if you go with loop through entire grid, then what happen when i have 10000 rows bounded to my grid, it is slow down my performance or not? so it is not a right way to color the row.

Comment: @TejasVaishnav : First of all, it will be highly unlikely that grid will contain more than 1K rows. If you are using then design will go for a toss.

Answer (score 5):

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="student_class" HeaderText="student_class" 
            SortExpression="student_class" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [student]">
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code behind:

```
static string[,] ClassNames =
{
   {"A","Red"},
   {"B","Blue"},
   {"C","Pink"},
   {"D","Green"},
   // and so on
};
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string className = e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
    string color = "Black";
    for (int i = 0; i <= ClassNames.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        if (ClassNames[i, 0] == className)
        {
            color = ClassNames[i, 1];
            e.Row.Cells[2].ForeColor = Color.FromName(color);
            e.Row.Cells[2].BorderColor = Color.Black;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: this is a nice way. but my table consists 80 types of student_class.  so 80 cases ?!!! @Samiey Mehdi

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to style depend on the value, I must recommend you to do it client-side, by using Jquery or javaScript.
Also, it won't affect performance as it's on the client-side rather than doing it on [RowDataBound](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound?view=netframework-4.8)

**Code:  Using Client-Side** - (which i recommend more)
Here you can set as many conditions to depend on your class values, no need to write extra server-side code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".myGvClass").find("td").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text() == "Class B") {
                $(this).css("color", "Red");
            }
            
            if ($(this).text() == "Class A") {
                $(this).css("color", "Blue");
            }
          
            if ($(this).text() == "Class C") {
                $(this).css("color", "green");
            }
          //  ..... and so on
    });
```

**HTML markup:**

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="myGvClass">
 </asp:GridView>
```

**CodeBehind:**

```
 GridView1.DataSource = YourDataTable;
 GridView1.DataBind();
```

**ScreenShot:**

[image]

---

---

**Code: Using serverside**
Looping over Gridview rows at `myGridview_DataBound` event, and check condition cell value and set respective colors.

```
protected void myGridview_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= myGridview.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        string myClassVal = myGridview.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;
        if (myClassVal == "Class A")
        {
            myGridview.Rows[i].Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Green;
         }
        else if (myClassVal == "Class B")
        {
            myGridview.Rows[i].Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else 
        {
           myGridview.Rows[i].Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Orange;
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridview" runat="server" ondatabound="myGridview_DataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
myGridview.DataSource = YourDataTable;
myGridview.DataBind();
```

ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: but my problem is i have more than 20 classes . @Satinder singh

Comment: @ARATHY: instead of write 30 time in serverside at RowDataBound , you can do it in clientside

Comment: how is it ? @Satinder singh

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to skin a cat, but if you really don't want to use RowDataBound, you could use a TemplateColumn containing a styled control in its ItemTemplate.  E.g.

```
<asp:GridView ...>
  ...
  <Columns>
     ...
     <asp:TemplateField ...>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ... CssClass='<%# GetStudentCssClass(Eval("student_Class")) %>'>
            ...
            </asp:Panel>
         </ItemTemplate>
         ...
```

Comment: All the three answer are right and meets the OP requirement, but still OP is waiting for some magical solution, so that he wont have to write check for 80 values, or set 80 css etc etc,