# How to change the color of a gridview cell based on criteria?

Tags: asp.net

This is my gridview output. The Column and row will be binded dynamically.

```
Anand R         4:4:18  NULL    6:34:52  8:25:16     NULL

Arunkumar S     8:37:31 NULL    9:1:42   8:48:27     NULL

Bharathi R      6:12:24 NULL    8:45:40  11:39:12    12:27:26

Gnanaguru V     6:32:20 NULL    5:35:56  3:50:20     NULL

Ilayaraja K     7:37:30 NULL    10:1:15  8:58:43     NULL

Imran Khan S    7:46:48 NULL    12:15:4  NULL            NULL
```

I need output as if the cell value is greater than 8:30 hours means i need some color and below than 8:30 the cell should be in some color and for the null value the original remain same. So i need to loop through gridview rows and columns dynamically to check the condition. I am using following code in gridview rowdatabound but am not getting exact output..

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gvshowreport.Rows)                
         {                    
           for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)                    
            {                        
               if (i != 0)                        
                   {                           
                   string value = row.Cells[i].Text;

                        if (value != "&nbsp;")

                        {
                            string[] values = Regex.Split(value, ":");
                            int k = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
                            int m = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
                            int min = k * 60;
                            int add = min + m;
                            if (add <= 510)
                            {
                                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGreen;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleGoldenrod;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

First time my loop is running perfectly it taking the gridview first row and cell values. While next time loop running it again taking the same first row cell values. I think i have did mistake looping through the rows and columns...

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

```
  {

      foreach(TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)

        val = cell.Text;
  }
```

I have use this code to achieve my result.. Thanks for everyone posting

Comment: 'Not getting exact output' == Sometimes the colouring is right, sometimes wrong? What are the values wrongly coloured or not coloured?

Comment: You can try this:

replace forecolor with backcolor

[How to style Asp.net GridView cells with colour based on cell valu][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670189/how-to-style-asp-net-gridview-cells-with-colour-based-on-cell-value/18671211#18671211

Comment: @Amber first time my loop is running perfectly it taking the gridview first row  cell values. While next time loop running it again taking the same gridview first row cell values. I think i have did mistake looping through the rows and columns...

Answer (score 1):

as your code, you should replace "e.Row.Cells[i]" with variable "row"

Comment: Its not working, the problem is every time the loop running its taking first row cell values only

Answer (score 1):

We would change the color of cell in Row_dataBound Event of Gridview

When a single record bind with a gridView Row_dataBound event fires

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
          //Your Cell Control Find, than change the color according to condition
     }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Please mark it answer if it helps you